# Get list of all currently registered NSURLProtocol subclasses?

Tags: ios, nsurlprotocol

What is the correct way to determine all NSURLProtocol subclasses that are currently registered in an app? [In the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLProtocol_Class/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001700-SW2), I only see methods for `+ (BOOL)registerClass:(Class)protocolClass` and `+ (void)unregisterClass:(Class)protocolClass`.

Does anyone know of a way to do this?  I am working on an app that has several NSURLProtocols that register and deregister at unpredictable intervals, and need to debug when certain protocols might be mangling my responses.

**EDIT:** 
I have tried `[[[NSURLSession sharedSession] configuration] protocolClasses]` but it does not show protocols I have registered myself.

Comment: 95% chance there isn't a public method for doing this. You will probably have to resort to using a category or method swizzling on `registerClass:` and `unregisterClass:`.

Comment: That sucks. Thanks for the help tho!

Answer (score 0):

The protocolClasses method returns an array that you provide when creating the session.  It doesn't have any connection to the array of protocols that have been globally registered in shared session/NSURLConnection-land, beyond that I **think** that each session's protocols are the union of those two arrays.

Given that you are presumably in control of your protocols, your best bet would probably be to store each protocol (or the name of each protocol) in an easily accessible dictionary (e.g. in your app delegate or something) when you register it and remove it when you unregister it.  That way, you'll have some notion of the current state of the world, +/- a few milliseconds and ignoring concurrency.